# How much Typescript is syntax wise different than es6 / es7

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecma

How much Typescript is syntax wise different than es6 / es7 . 
We have code like this in Typescript:

```
class demo {
    demoProp:any;
    constructor () {
        //...
    }
}
```

But `es6` doesn't require `:any` after property to declare it?
So should I keep using Typescript or should I learn `es6` directly as it is standard `JavaScript`.
Note:- I am aware that `TypeScript` is said to be type based and also superset of `es6`. But will `ecma script`  likely be `TypeScript` in near future or in its next version `7` or `8`

Comment: No, ECMAScript will never become TypeScript.

Comment: as far as i'm aware there's no intention to introduce types into javascript and so typescript will not be as javascript

Comment: @Bergi I would not be so affirmative about the future. Eccmascript 4, which was abandoned, had static typing. Wikipedia cites "political differences" as the reason to abandon version 4. Not much is more volatile than politicians and political differences.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder: ECMAScript needs to stay backwards-compatible and will never enforce static typing.

Comment: than why typescript introduced that ???

Comment: @Bergi Who is talking about enforcement ? Unless you set the 'noImplicitAny` flag in Typescript, there is no enforcement either

Comment: @BrunoGrieder can you elaborate your last comment

Comment: @RavinderPayal straight copy from Angular2 doc: "When the noImplicitAny flag is false (the default), the compiler silently defaults the type of a variable to any if it cannot infer the type based on how the variable is used"

Comment: Not for now but maybe "use strong" in JavaScript will become a thing... https://developers.google.com/v8/experiments

Comment: May I ask what's point of down-voting a question? And yeah It's an opinion based question, and programmer also require opinions for going ahead, and deciding if he/she should learn a specific technology or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TypeScript you have types, access modifiers and properties:

```
class demo {
    public demoProp: any;
    constructor(demoProp:any) {
        this.demoProp = demoProp;
    }
}
```

You can also have generic types and interfaces:

```
interface Demo<T> {
    demoProp: T
}

class demo<T> implements Demo<T> {
    public demoProp: T;
    constructor(demoProp: T) {
        this.demoProp = demoProp;
    }
}
```

Generics and interfaces are not available in ES6 because they only make sense when you have types.

In ES6 you don't have properties, types, or access modifiers:

```
class demo {
    constructor(demoProp) {
        this.demoProp = demoProp;
    }
}
```

I would learn TypeScript because the differences are not huge and if you learn TypeScript you will also know ES6 so you will learn two languages in one shot.

About JavaScript becoming TypeScript is [not likely but is not impossible](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/03/Google-StrongMode-SoundScript-V8).